# ASP.NET ajax control toolkit ModalPopupExtender issue with div overflow

Tags: javascript, css, asp.net, ajax, ajaxcontroltoolkit

I have a checkboxlist inside a modal popup . I want to wrap the checkboxlist in a div with overflow-y:scroll css so I get a vertical scrollbar around the checkboxlist.  However, when I click on the scrollbar of the overflow div, the mouse locks in position on the scrollbar and starts moving the modal popup itself.  I cannot free it from the scrollbar and stop moving the modal popup around. It's just stuck there

I also get a JavaScript Error: Unable to get property 'scrollLeft' of undefined or null reference

Not sure what's going on. Probably something interfering the ajax control toolkit plumbing.

Comment: This is not an issue in Chrome and FireFox. Seems like only IE

Answer (score 0):

well the workaround solution was to set the overflow on the modal popup div itself and set the PopupDragHandleControlID to empty with RepositionMode none so the popup is not draggable. this fixed the overflow div scrollbar on the checkbox list inside the popup